# Add/remove html markups according to the content of RenderBody()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor-2

In my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<section class="container content-section text-center">
    @RenderBody()
</section>
```

I only want to have the "section" around when the "body" is not the home page.

I was thinking of detecting url, but soon realized that I will have many Urls bound to the website, it's not the smart way to do it.

So is there anything I could do to make the "section" wrapper smarter enough to know when to appear when not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check that which controller is currently executing its action and put check on HomePage Controller :

```
@{
    var controllerName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    var actionName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
}

@if(controllerName == "HomePage" && actionName == "yourActionName")
{

    @RenderBody()

}
else
{
<section class="container content-section text-center">
@RenderBody()
</section>
}
```

Comment: Hi Ehsan, thank you for your reply. But I also need to know which Action. Because I only need to remove the "section" when it's home page.

Comment: @Franva Action name is also stored in `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]`. Just add it to condition.

Comment: @Franva you can get executing action as well as Yeldar pointed out

Answer (score 0):

As for me, I wouldn't use conditions.
It is kind of **hack** but **not solution**. Next time you need something to be changed, you will add more and more IFs?

Use two layouts.

*_LayoutWithSection.cshtml:*

```
 // ...
 <section class="container content-section text-center">
     @RenderBody
 </section>
 // ...
```

*_Layout.cshtml:*

```
 // ...
 @RenderBody
 // ...
```

*Home/Index.cshtml:*

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutWithSection.cshtml";
}
// ...
```

*_ViewStart.cshtml:*

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
// ...
```

Comment: Huh, I'm not sure about it. There are hundred lines of code in the _Layout.cshtml. Creating a 99.9% similar layout for accomplishing this task is not idea.

Comment: Oh. I usually don't have hundred lines of code in my layouts :) In your case, Ehsan's solution looks pretty applicable.